# before-save-hook not working with use-package and custom mode

Tags: hooks, major-mode, use-package

I wrote a little derived mode for the kage shader language, it's derived from go-mode (syntax is the same). I also like to use gofmt, but it's just not loading the hook.

Here's the mode:

```lisp
(define-derived-mode kage-mode go-mode "Kage shader script"
  "Kage mode is a major mode for editing Ebitengine Kage shader files"
  ;; disable lsp just in case, kage  is not supported properly by lsp,
  ;; even if kage code looks like go, it isn't
  (lsp-mode nil))

(defun kage-gofmt-before-save ()
  (interactive)
  (when (eq major-mode 'kage-mode) (gofmt)))

(autoload 'kage-mode "kage-mode")
(autoload 'kage-gofmt-before-save "execute gofmt on write")

(provide 'kage-mode)
```

And this is the config:

```lisp
(use-package kage-mode
  :ensure nil ;; installed in site-lisp
  :defer nil
  :mode "\\.kg\\'"
  :commands kage-gofmt-before-save
  :init
  (add-hook 'before-save-hook
            #'kage-gofmt-before-save
            nil t))
```

I tried many variations (like putting the add-hook into the :config section, using a lambda() instead of a direct hook, etc). Nothing works so far, that is, when I open a kage file, `before-save-hook` is empty.

When I execute `kage-gofmt-before-save` it works.

How can I add that hook to `before-save-hook`?

Comment: Did you check the value of the hook? Does it include your function?

Comment: "Nothing works so far" - how do you check whether it worked?

Comment: Well, when I open a kage file, then the hook variable `before-safe-hook` is empty. And if I change some code in the file and safe it, nothing will be corrected (what would happen if the hook worked, since it executes `gofmt -s` on the buffer).

Comment: Should be `save`, not `safe`: are you spelling it correctly?

Comment: I only spelled it wrong here in the question, in my config I use `before-save-hook`. But I corrected the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be configured via `kage-mode-hook`. This is the fixed mode:

```lisp
(define-derived-mode kage-mode go-mode "Kage shader script"
  "Kage mode is a major mode for editing Ebitengine Kage shader files")

(defun kage-gofmt-before-save ()
  (interactive)
  (when (eq major-mode 'kage-mode) (gofmt)))

(autoload 'kage-mode "kage-mode")
(autoload 'kage-gofmt-before-save "execute gofmt on write")

(provide 'kage-mode)
```

And this is the use-package code I use:

```lisp
(use-package kage-mode
  :ensure nil ;; installed in site-lisp
  :defer nil
  :mode "\\.kg\\'"
  :commands kage-gofmt-before-save

  :init
  (defun tvd-kage-install-hooks()
    (remove-hook 'before-save-hook #'lsp-format-buffer t)
    (remove-hook 'before-save-hook #'lsp-organize-imports t)
    (add-hook 'before-save-hook #'kage-gofmt-before-save t t))

  :config
  (add-hook 'kage-mode-hook #'tvd-kage-install-hooks)
  (setq lsp-warn-no-matched-clients nil))
```

Here I remove the lsp-mode symbols from the `before-save-hook` (which have been added via `go-mode-hook` and add my own. I also disable the lsp-mode warning about non matching client.

Comment: `(run-hooks 'kage-mode-hook)` is not necessary.  By default, the mode function generated by `(define-derived-mode kage-mode ...)` will run `kage-mode-hook`.

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed w/o it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `use-package`, but I imagine it evaluates the `:init` form exactly once, and yet you're passing LOCAL to `add-hook` in that init form.  I imagine that's a mistake and the cause of your problem.

Comment: Indeed, when I remove the local flag, it works. However, it's not local then anymore.

Comment: Well yes -- it's no good having a local hook function in whichever single arbitrary buffer happened to be current at the time your code was initially loaded.  If the intention is for it to be local in buffers using `kage-mode` then do it in your `kage-mode` body.

Comment: And if the idea is not to force that on people, then use `kage-mode-hook`.

Comment: I finally solved it. The primary problem was the `go-mode-hook`s. These have been loaded because kage-mode derives from it. I removed these hooks, used `kage-mode-hook` as suggested (thanks!) and now it works as I want.

Comment: Right, that all makes sense.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19295380/324105 might be useful reading regarding the sequence of events for derived modes, in case you're still missing any pieces of that puzzle.